# How nested filters work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I guess I don't fully understand how nested filters work.

I've created highly nested (and slightly silly) filter object:

```
L = iter(range(100000))

for i in range(10000):
    L = filter(lambda x, i=i: x != i, L)
```

Each of the additional filter level just trim the iterator some more (actually by one item).

Now when I call this filter object I expected all the nested conditions to be tested with each `next` call. How else can we know that the `next` value successfully passes all these condition? Indeed the first call takes a very long time to execute, but then each additional iteration is considerably shorter:

```
import time

j = 0
lasttime = time.time()
for x in L:
    curtime = time.time()
    print(x, curtime - lasttime)
    lasttime = curtime
    j += 1
    if j > 10:
        break
```

The result is:

```
10000 9.558015823364258
10001 0.0020017623901367188
10002 0.002501964569091797
10003 0.0020017623901367188
10004 0.0025022029876708984
10005 0.0025017261505126953
10006 0.0020020008087158203
10007 0.002001047134399414
10008 0.002501249313354492
10009 0.002002716064453125
10010 0.0
```

What's under the hood? How is this happening? I'll appreciate some explanation into the inner working that creates this.

Comment: Are these results in python2 or python3?

Comment: What exactly is unexpected here? Of course the iteration will take significantly longer, after all the first 10000 elements get discarded, so the "first" value is actually the 10001st.

Comment: Incidentally, nesting filters this deep is likely to cause a stack overflow. Try to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first iteration has to apply about 50 million predicate tests to reject the first 10 thousand elements, so it takes ages. Every iteration after that only needs to apply 10 thousand tests to accept the next element, so they're about 5000 times faster. The variation you see between later iterations is just noise; it's not significant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 50 million figure?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: On average, each of the first 10000 elements needs to go through about half of the 10000 predicates to be rejected.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought you meant each element in the first 10 thousand had to go through 50 million tests.